# When $\int |f|=\left|\int f\right|$ holds?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I was just wondering when did the equality hold for the following inequality:
$$\left|\int_{R^d}f(x)\, d x\right|\leq\int_{R^d}|f(x)|\, d x$$
where $f:R^d\to R$ is Lebesgue integrable on $R^d$.

Obviously, if $f\geq0$ a.e. on $R^d$, the equality will hold trivially, but I don't know whether it is the only case?

Comment: Is that Riemann integral ?

Comment: Is $f:\mathbb{R}^d\to\mathbb{R}$ ?

Comment: if $f(x) \geq 0$ almost everywhere or  $f(x) \leq 0$ almost everywhere

Comment: Real-valued case: $\epsilon \int f=\int |f|$ if and only if $\int|f|-\epsilon f=0$. Note that $|f|-\epsilon f\geq 0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $E_+$ be the set where $f\geq 0$ and let $E_-$ be the set where $f<0$. Then $\int f=\int_{E_+}f+\int_{E_-}f=\int_{E_+}|f|-\int_{E-}|f|$. This is equal to $\int|f|=\int_{E_+}|f|+\int_{E_-}|f|$ in absolute value if and only if either $\int_{E_+}f$ or $\int_{E_-}f$ is $0$. An integral $\int_{E_+}f$ of a non-negative function is positive if and only if $f>0$ almost everywhere. Thus you have equality if and only if $f\geq 0$ almost everywhere or $f\leq 0$ almost everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A_+=f^{-1}((0,\infty))$, $A_-=f^{-1}((-\infty,0))$.
Then let $I_\pm=\int_{A_\pm}f(x)\,\mathrm dx$.
We have $I_\pm=0$ iff $\mu(A_\pm)=0$, $\left|\int_{\mathbb R^d}f(x)\,\mathrm dx\right|=|I_++I_-|$, $\int_{\mathbb R^d}|f(x)|\,\mathrm dx=I_+-I_-$, hence equality iff one of $I_\pm$ is zero, and that is iff one of $A_\pm$ has measure zero.